# Java Apache POI - Adding table in all sheets of a workbook throwing error in MS Excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI 3.17 and XSSFWorkbook to create an excel workbook.
The workbook contains multiple sheets and I am trying to add data in a table in every sheet.

Java Main Method

```
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    for (String sheet : sheets)
    {
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(sheet);
        List<String> colNames = Arrays.asList("Column1","Column2","Column3");

        createTable(sheet,colNames);

        for (int r = 0; r <= 1; r++)
        {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(r);
            for (int c = 0; c < colNames.size(); c++)
            {
                XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(c);
                cell.setCellValue("some value");
            }

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < colNames.size(); i++)
        {
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
        }
    }
```

Method for adding a table in a sheet

```
private void createTable(XSSFSheet sheet, List<String> colNames)
{
    XSSFTable table = sheet.createTable();
    CTTable cttable = table.getCTTable();

    CellReference startCellReference = new CellReference(0, 0);

    CellReference endCellReference = new CellReference(2,colNames.size());
    AreaReference areaReference = new AreaReference(startCellReference, endCellReference, SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);

    cttable.setDisplayName("SummaryData_" + sheet.getSheetName());
    cttable.setId(1);
    cttable.setName("SummaryData_" + sheet.getSheetName());
    cttable.setRef(areaReference.formatAsString());
    cttable.setTotalsRowShown(false);

    CTTableStyleInfo styleInfo = cttable.addNewTableStyleInfo();
    styleInfo.setName("TableStyleMedium13");
    styleInfo.setShowColumnStripes(false);
    styleInfo.setShowRowStripes(true);

    CTTableColumns columns = cttable.addNewTableColumns();
    columns.setCount(colNames.size());
    for (int i = 1; i <= colNames.size(); i++)
    {
        CTTableColumn column = columns.addNewTableColumn();
        column.setId(i);
        column.setName(colNames.get(i - 1));
    }
}
```

If there is only one sheet then excel opens up properly in MS-Excel, but if there are more than 1 sheet then excel gives an error on opening the workbook.

[image: Error on opening the workbook]

If I click on yes then I get the repair summary for the table

[image: Repair Summary]

Although data is present in the workbook.

If I remove the table and add the data directly into the sheet then it works properly without any error.

Can someone please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using an old version of Apache POI? What happens when you upgrade to the latest stable supported version?

Comment: Sorry but right now I can't upgrade the version as its legacy code and I am just adding new functionality to it

Answer (score 3):

Multiple problems here:

1. The variable  `sheet`  cannot be a `String` and a `XSSFSheet`  the same time.
2. The `colNames.size()` gets 3 in your case. So your `endCellReference`  is `D3` and your `areaReference` is `A1:D3`, thus one column too wide. It would must be `A1:C3`. So: `CellReference endCellReference = new CellReference(2, colNames.size()-1);`.
3. Don't set all table's Ids to 1 manually using `cttable.setId(1)`. Each table needs its own Id. The `sheet.createTable()` had done that properly already.
4. Sheet's cell values must match the table's column names. So you cannot set "some value" in all cells. The values of the cells which display the table's column names must match the table's column names.

Complete example corrected:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.*;

import java.util.*;

public class CreateTablePOI3 {

 private static void createTable(XSSFSheet sheet, List<String> colNames) {

  XSSFTable table = sheet.createTable();
  CTTable cttable = table.getCTTable();

  CellReference startCellReference = new CellReference(0, 0);
  //CellReference endCellReference = new CellReference(2, colNames.size()); //one column too wide
  CellReference endCellReference = new CellReference(2, colNames.size()-1);
  AreaReference areaReference = new AreaReference(startCellReference, endCellReference, SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);

  cttable.setDisplayName("SummaryData_" + sheet.getSheetName());
  //cttable.setId(1); // Don't set table's Id manually. The sheet.createTable() is doing that properly.
  cttable.setName("SummaryData_" + sheet.getSheetName());
  cttable.setRef(areaReference.formatAsString());
  cttable.setTotalsRowShown(false);

  CTTableStyleInfo styleInfo = cttable.addNewTableStyleInfo();
  styleInfo.setName("TableStyleMedium13");
  styleInfo.setShowColumnStripes(false);
  styleInfo.setShowRowStripes(true);

  CTTableColumns columns = cttable.addNewTableColumns();
  columns.setCount(colNames.size());
  for (int i = 1; i <= colNames.size(); i++) {
   CTTableColumn column = columns.addNewTableColumn();
   column.setId(i);
   column.setName(colNames.get(i - 1));
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  List<String> sheetNames = Arrays.asList("Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3");

  XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  for (String sheetName : sheetNames) {
   XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(sheetName);
   List<String> colNames = Arrays.asList("Column1","Column2","Column3");

   createTable(sheet, colNames);

   for (int r = 0; r <= 2; r++) {
    XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(r);
    for (int c = 0; c < colNames.size(); c++) {
     XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(c);
     //cell.setCellValue("some value"); //sheet's cell values must match the table's column names  
     if (r == 0) {
      cell.setCellValue(colNames.get(c));
     } else {
      cell.setCellValue("some value");
     }
    }
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < colNames.size(); i++) {
    sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
   }
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./Excel.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

---

The above had worked using **Apache POI 3.17** version as mentioned in Question.

Current Apache POI versions of 2023 do not have `XSSFSheet.createTable()` without parameters anymore. To make this code work using current Apache POI versions of 2023, one could change:

```
...
  //XSSFTable table = sheet.createTable();
  XSSFTable table = sheet.createTable(null);
...
```

But the whole usage of the underlying `CT*` classes is not more necessary.

The current code should look like so:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import java.util.*;

public class CreateTablePOI4 {

 private static void createTable(XSSFSheet sheet, List<String> colNames) { 
  CellReference startCellReference = new CellReference(0, 0);
  CellReference endCellReference = new CellReference(2, colNames.size()-1);
  AreaReference areaReference = new AreaReference(startCellReference, endCellReference, SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
  XSSFTable dataTable = sheet.createTable(areaReference);
  //dataTable.setName("SummaryData_" + sheet.getSheetName());
  dataTable.setDisplayName("SummaryData_" + sheet.getSheetName());
  //this styles the table as Excel would do per default
  dataTable.getCTTable().addNewTableStyleInfo();
  XSSFTableStyleInfo style = (XSSFTableStyleInfo)dataTable.getStyle();
  style.setName("TableStyleMedium13");
  style.setShowColumnStripes(false);
  style.setShowRowStripes(true);
  dataTable.getCTTable().addNewAutoFilter().setRef(areaReference.formatAsString());
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  List<String> sheetNames = Arrays.asList("Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3");

  XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  for (String sheetName : sheetNames) {
   XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(sheetName);
   List<String> colNames = Arrays.asList("Column1","Column2","Column3");

   for (int r = 0; r <= 2; r++) {
    XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(r);
    for (int c = 0; c < colNames.size(); c++) {
     XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(c);
     //cell.setCellValue("some value"); //sheet's cell values must match the table's column names  
     if (r == 0) {
      cell.setCellValue(colNames.get(c));
     } else {
      cell.setCellValue("some value");
     }
    }
   }
   
   createTable(sheet, colNames);

   for (int i = 0; i < colNames.size(); i++) {
    sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
   }
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./Excel.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Note, that `createTable(sheet, colNames)` gets called **after** the sheet data is filled. The new version  of `XSSFSheet.createTable(AreaReference)` gets all the information for table columns out of the filled `AreaReference`.

Comment: I have modified the original code to post it here, mistakes like using the same variable name "sheet" and cell reference size are not there.
But I am using setId(), will remove that and test it again, thanks :)

Comment: Still not working, removed setId() from the table, used the first row for setting the column names. Excel is still giving the error and on clicking yes it says data is recovered and complete data is present in the sheet
Its working fine for only 1 sheet, don't know what's the issue with multiple sheets :(

Comment: @Shashank Gupta: My answer shows a complete example which creates a `Excel.xlsx` having three sheets containing a table each. It is tested and works and `Excel` is able opening that file without problems.

Comment: I confirm it does not work for me neither

Comment: @Alexandre Liscia: Have updated my answer to fit for current Apache POI versions of 2023.

Answer (score -1):

The previous answer is not working with modern version of POI.

Sheet.createReference() now needs an AreaReference as parameter.

So I switched some lines to have it :

```
CellReference startCellReference = new CellReference(0, 0);
    //CellReference endCellReference = new CellReference(2, colNames.size()); //one column too wide
    CellReference endCellReference = new CellReference(2, colNames.size() - 1);
    AreaReference areaReference = new AreaReference(startCellReference, endCellReference, SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);

    XSSFTable table = sheet.createTable(areaReference);
    CTTable cttable = table.getCTTable();

    cttable.setDisplayName("SummaryData_" + sheet.getSheetName());
    //cttable.setId(1); // Don't set table's Id manually. The sheet.createTable() is doing that properly.
    cttable.setName("SummaryData_" + sheet.getSheetName());
    cttable.setRef(areaReference.formatAsString());
    cttable.setTotalsRowShown(false);
```

It was still not working. BUT, if you pass null as parameter instead of a valid AreaReference, then it works :

```
 CellReference startCellReference = new CellReference(0, 0);
    //CellReference endCellReference = new CellReference(2, colNames.size()); //one column too wide
    CellReference endCellReference = new CellReference(2, colNames.size() - 1);
    AreaReference areaReference = new AreaReference(startCellReference, endCellReference, SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);

    XSSFTable table = sheet.createTable(null); // Look HERE
    CTTable cttable = table.getCTTable();

    cttable.setDisplayName("SummaryData_" + sheet.getSheetName());
    //cttable.setId(1); // Don't set table's Id manually. The sheet.createTable() is doing that properly.
    cttable.setName("SummaryData_" + sheet.getSheetName());
    cttable.setRef(areaReference.formatAsString());
    cttable.setTotalsRowShown(false);
```

I don't get why POI is not working when passing a valid AreaReference but now it works, and that's what is important.